# Jenkinsfile with Dockerfile in a specific folder

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

This is driving me nuts: I am trying to build a Docker image from a Dockerfile in a specific folder of my repository using a scripted Jenkins Pipeline, but it doesn't get the correct path.

This is the line in the `Jenkinsfile`:

```
def customImage = docker.build("km3pipe:${env.BUILD_ID}",
                               "-f ${dockerfile} ${DOCKER_FILES_DIR}")
```

As you can see in the Jenkinslog below, the variables are correctly resolved (I also double checked the workspace, everything is fine), but it seems to ignore the second argument `.dockerfiles`:

```
[py365] + docker build -t km3pipe:13 -f py365 ./dockerfiles
[py365] unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: 
        lstat /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/f-docker-image-names-for-ci-2DCL5RJ7AMH7K
        IB6OCBTD57EC5DUGYZTQE5EQ6KGOSPXMUOVJP6Q/py365: no such file or directory
```

According to the docs (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/), this should work:

> It is possible to pass other arguments to docker build by adding them
>   to the second argument of the `build()` method. When passing arguments
>   this way, the last value in the that string must be the path to the
>   docker file.
>
> This example overrides the default `Dockerfile` by passing the -f flag:
>
> ```
> node {
>     checkout scm
>     def dockerfile = 'Dockerfile.test'
>     def customImage = docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}", "-f ${dockerfile} ./dockerfiles") 
> }
> ```
>
> Builds `my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}` from the `Dockerfile` found at `./dockerfiles/Dockerfile.test`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is saying that there is no file named py365 in this folder. You're right the docker.build step is not using the path to run the build.

The documentation missed that you must include the directory in the dockerfile statement:

```
def customImage = docker.build("km3pipe:${env.BUILD_ID}",
                               "-f ${DOCKER_FILES_DIR}/${dockerfile} ${DOCKER_FILES_DIR}")
```

Comment: Yes, as I wrote above. It seems to look for the file in the workspace directory, as you can see in the log, and not in `workspace/dockerfiles`, where it should...

Comment: I'm sorry that should be a comment. I've tried and you're right, there is a bug because it doesn't use that directory to run docker build. I got it to work using a dir step, just edited the answer.

Comment: Many thanks, this seems to be a reasonable workaround. However (i am a groovy-noob), is there a way to define `customImage` outside of the `dir` closure? Like `def customImage = ''` before I enter the `dir`?

Comment: I just did it like that, and it works. Not sure if it's nice though, due to duck typing ;)

Comment: I posted a reference to your answer on https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-51576

Comment: Even better, there is no need for workarounds. Just the documentation was bad: when declaring the Dockerfile you should include the path, just re-edited the answer

Comment: Ah ok! However, it’s still not ideal due to information duplication, thus I prefer your first suggestion ;)